# Python: Data fitting with scipy.optimize.curve_fit with sigma = 0

Tags: python-2.7, optimization, scipy, curve-fitting, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to fit a curve with scipy.optimize.curve_fit and it works pretty good so far, except in the case that a value in my sigma array is zero. I understand that the algorithm can't handle this, as I divide by zero in this case. From the scipy documentation:

**sigma** : None or M-length sequence, optional
If not None, the uncertainties in the ydata array. These are used as weights in the least-squares problem i.e. minimising np.sum( ((f(xdata, *popt) - ydata) / sigma)**2 ) If None, the uncertainties are assumed to be 1.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = [0.125, 0.375, 0.625, 0.875, 1.125, 1.375, 1.625, 1.875, 2.125, 2.375, 2.625, 2.875, 3.125, 3.375, 3.625, 3.875, 4.125, 4.375]
y_para = [0, 0, 0.0414, 0.2164, 0.2616, 0.4254, 0.5698, 0.5921, 0.6286, 0.6452, 0.5879, 0.6032, 0.6667, 0.6325, 0.7629, 0.7164, 0.7091, 0.7887]
err = [0, 0, 0.0391, 0.0331, 0.0943, 0.0631, 0.1219, 0.1063, 0.0912, 0.0516, 0.0365, 0.0327, 0.0227, 0.103, 0.1344, 0.0697, 0.0114, 0.0465]   

def logistic_growth(x, A1, A2, x_0, p):
    return A2 + (A1-A2)/(1+(x/x_0)**p)

x_plot = np.linspace(0, 4.5, 100)

bounds_para = ([0.,0,-np.inf,-np.inf],[0.0000000001, 1,np.inf,np.inf])

paras, paras_cov = curve_fit(logistic_growth, x, y_para, bounds = bounds_para, sigma = err, absolute_sigma=True)
para_curve = logistic_growth(x_plot, *paras)

plt.figure()
plt.errorbar(x,y_para, err, color = 'b', fmt = 'o', label = "Data")
plt.plot(x_plot, para_curve, color = 'b', label = "Fit")    
plt.show()
```

Executing this without the sigma-option in curve_fit works fine, but including it raises:

```
ValueError: Residuals are not finite in the initial point.
```

, which results from the zeros in the err-array.
Does anyone know a way to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just drop the variable? If it has zero variance it cannot contribute in any meaningful way to your analysis.

Comment: This works out pretty good. Maybe this is even the only way to solve this correctly. But actually I'd like to consider these data points as well, because the missing errorbar is the result that the value for this data point didn't vary for multiple replicates. This might also happen for non-zero values, but is more unlikely. Setting a very low value for the error in this case also doesn't do the trick, as it completely messes up the curve. I will still go with your suggestion, as it gives good result, seems statistically correct and solves the problem. So, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is what the **scipy** doc says about the **curve_fit** **sigma** parameter: 'These are used as weights in the least-squares problem ...' Then, in my opinion, they should be inverse to the errors. Here's what I suggest.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = [0.125, 0.375, 0.625, 0.875, 1.125, 1.375, 1.625, 1.875, 2.125, 2.375, 2.625, 2.875, 3.125, 3.375, 3.625, 3.875, 4.125, 4.375]
y_para = [0, 0, 0.0414, 0.2164, 0.2616, 0.4254, 0.5698, 0.5921, 0.6286, 0.6452, 0.5879, 0.6032, 0.6667, 0.6325, 0.7629, 0.7164, 0.7091, 0.7887]
err = [0, 0, 0.0391, 0.0331, 0.0943, 0.0631, 0.1219, 0.1063, 0.0912, 0.0516, 0.0365, 0.0327, 0.0227, 0.103, 0.1344, 0.0697, 0.0114, 0.0465]   

weights = [1/max(_,0.001) for _ in err]
print (weights)

def logistic_growth(x, A1, A2, x_0, p):
    return A2 + (A1-A2)/(1+(x/x_0)**p)

x_plot = np.linspace(0, 4.5, 100)

bounds_para = ([0.,0,-np.inf,-np.inf],[0.0000000001, 1,np.inf,np.inf])

paras, paras_cov = curve_fit(logistic_growth, x, y_para, bounds = bounds_para, 
    absolute_sigma=True,
    sigma = weights)
para_curve = logistic_growth(x_plot, *paras)

plt.figure()
plt.errorbar(x,y_para, err, color = 'b', fmt = 'o', label = "Data")
plt.plot(x_plot, para_curve, color = 'b', label = "Fit")    
plt.show()
```

This results in the following plot, where those initial data points are made to lie very close to the fitted line.

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: I think the errors are used inversely in minimising the least-squares problem. From scipy doc: "weights in the least-squares problem i.e minimising np.sum( ((f(xdata, *popt) - ydata) / sigma)**2 )", meaning that a greater error/sigma value will result in a lower weight for the respective data point. I actually tried your suggesed approach before and know it yields a good result for this special case, but I think its not the correct approach for this kind of problem.

Comment: I suppose my question is, should the zero values for *err* for some of the data points be taken to mean that those points have been precisely determined or that they have been imprecisely determined? Do successively higher values of *err* imply greater or less precision?